# Convert labels to annotations in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, convert, annotation

When using ArcMap it's possible to convert labels to annotations. How does this work in QGIS without a plugin or Python?

Comment: What is the difference between a label and an annotation? How do they work in Arc?

Comment: As I remember in ArcGis you can not do very much with labels, it is an automatic thing. If you want to move or manipulate them, you have to convert the labels into an annotation-layer. This is a different concept than in QGIS, where you can manipulate labels with different tools. In QGIS annotations are not bound to any features in your vectorlayers. So you should ask yourself first: do I need to convert my labels into annotations?

Comment: @Erik Labels are automatically generated dependend on zoom, extract etc. You can't edit them freehand. Annotations are objects resolved from the labeled feature. So when automatic label creation leads to unappropriate results in some cases, you can convert the label and edit them by hand to get the result you want.

Comment: @eurojam: What are the tools to edit labels in QGIS? I only found the settings in the layer properties, which did not bring the results I needed. When labeling 100 objects an getting 5 unappropriate labels converting the labels into annotations and putting these 5 by hand into the right position is the fastest and easiest way of getting the layout done. How do you handle unfitting labels?

Comment: What kind of edits do you expect to do?

Comment: Is this really only about moving labels?

Comment: @Vico: see https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-labeling-toolbar for example

Comment: @Erik In the last step, yes.

Comment: @eurojam Thanks, moving labels may be a solution.